# Compare user input to known string

Tags: python, string, user-interface, easygui

I'm trying to compare a word provided by the user (e.g `"orange"`) to a list of words I have in a text file like the following:

menu.txt

```
apple 
banana
orange
grape
mango
```

The user input comes from an `easygui.enterbox`.  I'm never getting the result I expect because it is having a hard time comparing the strings.  Here is my code.

```
import easygui     

count = 0
dish = easygui.enterbox("enter your favourite dish:")
with open("menu.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for item1 in content:
        if item1 == dish :
            easygui.msgbox("order taken.thankyou")
            count = count + 1
            continue
        if count == 0 :
            easygui.msgbox("plz order some other item")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that you need to add .strip() to both item and dish to make sure all spaces or end of line symbols are not part of the string

Answer (score 1):

`f.readlines()` returns the items with line endings. You want to `.strip()` the newline characters and extra spaces. There is `else:` for `for` loops; you want to use it here; if a match is found you `break` out of the loop; `else` report an error. Also, indent by 4 spaces, it is the standard.

```
import easygui     

dish = easygui.enterbox("enter your favourite dish:")
with open("menu.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for item1 in content:
        item1 = item1.strip()
        if item1 == dish:
            easygui.msgbox("order taken. thankyou")
            # it can match 1 dish only; so we can exit now
            break

    else:
        easygui.msgbox("plz order some other item")
```

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all you don't need `readlines()` to loop over your lines,second you need to [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) your lines before compare!because those contain new line character `\n`!

```
import easygui     
count = 0
dish = easygui.enterbox("enter your favourite dish:")
with open("menu.txt") as f:
      for item1 in f:
            if item1.strip() == dish :
                  easygui.msgbox("order taken.thankyou")
                  count = count + 1
            continue
      if count == 0 :
                  easygui.msgbox("plz order some other item")
```